# Custom sort in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sort an array of objects into a custom order - that is, one where the sort is not logic based but arbitrary.

I currently have it working like this:

```
sortedAssessments() {
  return [
    this.assessments.find(assessment => assessment.id === 14),
    this.assessments.find(assessment => assessment.id === 15),
    this.assessments.find(assessment => assessment.id === 4),
    this.assessments.find(assessment => assessment.id === 17)
  ]
}
```

But running `Array.find` 4 times seems quite expensive. Is there a way this could be achieved using `Array.sort`?

Comment: yes, look up how to use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a priority array

```
var priority = [14, 15, 4, 17];
```

Now sort as per this `priority` using `indexOf`

```
sortedAssessments() {
     return this.assessments.sort( (a, b) => priority.indexOf(a.id) - priority.indexOf(b.id) )
}
```